# Is it Possible to Query Multiple Databases with WCF Data Services?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-data-services

I have data being inserted into multiple databases with the same schema. The multiple databases exist for performance reasons.

I need to create a WCF service that a client can use to query the databases. However from the client's point of view, there is only 1 database. By this I mean when a client performs a query, it should query all databases and return the combined results.

I also need to provide the flexibility for the client to define its own queries. Therefore I am looking into WCF Data Services, which provides the very nice functionality for client specified queries.

So far, it seems that a DataService can only make a query to a single database. I found no override that would allow me to dispatch queries to multiple databases.

Does anyone know if it is possible for a WCF Data Service to query against multiple databases with the same schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I posted the question on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dataservices/thread/adfaa1ae-6b24-48c1-baf5-8cf19de59b4a) and found out that it will require a lot of effort.

It involves [creating your own data service provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx), which is tricky and can be a lot of work. On top of that merging results with sorting + paging will be a task that is far too complicated and risky for what I am willing to do. For example, how do I query multiple databases for page 1000 sorted by the Name column? I would essentially have to query all data from all databases, sort by Name, then select the 1000th page.

Comment: Is this still the case 4 years later?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write a facade service that will dispatch the query to the underlying - either in sequence or in parallel. You will typically create the facade in such a way that the WCF Data Service uses the Reflection Provider and you can use LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework for the underlying databases.

How to: Create a Data Service Using the Reflection Provider (WCF Data Services):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728281.aspx

HTH,

--larsw

Comment: That sounds like an excellent idea, however, I don't see any place where I can intercept the query and execute it on the multiple databases. Can you be more specific on how exactly this could be done?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to create a facade for my ObjectContext and roll my own IQueryable<T> implementation, which supports querying of multiple databases. However, this seems it would be very complicated. It would be nice to be able to inject my own functionality when the DataService performs the query.

Comment: After a day investigating how I could possibly accomplish this, I have come to the conclusion that I would have to create my own implementation of the IDataServiceProvider, which would essentially have to contain a re-implementation of the internal ObjectContextServiceProvider. This is too much effort, so I guess I'll have to look for another solution.

Comment: What about Query Interceptors? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx

Comment: QueryInterceptors only allows for modifications of the Expression before it is executed. It won't let me perform querying and merging of results.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use a different approach. I'm talking about Distributed Caches, such as Oracle Coherence or NCache. The structure is really transparent - you interact with in-memory database that is synchronized with your "backing map" - one or more databases.

There are a lot of interesting features in such caches. for example you can change a store strategy or build a backing map with a different databases (MS SQL, Oracle etc.)